# Why my trimmed image is blank and the imported image is so small?

Tags: image-processing

This is the first time I use Mathematica to do image processing, and I just want to remove the coordinate axes from this image.

Initially, I obtained the coordinates of the bottom-left corner as approximately `(8,6)` and the coordinates of the top-right corner as `(28,22)`.

However, when I applied `ImageTrim`, it resulted in a blank image.

Could there be a mistake in my understanding of this?

By the way, why my output of imported image is so small?

Thank you.

```
i = Import["C:\\image-xF-bw.png"]
ImageTrim[i, Rectangle[{8, 6}, {28, 22}]]
```

[image: image-xF-bw.png]
[image: blank output]
[image: bottom-left point coordinate]
[image: top-right point cooridnate]

Comment: or check this: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ExtractARegionFromAnImage.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The displaying size of an `Image[…]` is influenced by `ImageResolution` option:

[image]

So are the coordinates obtained by [Right-click] ▶ Get Coordinates. **At least in version 14**, the coordinates will be consistent with the *standard image coordinate system* (the coordinate system used by `ImageTrim`, etc., see the **Details and Options** section of `ImageTrim` for more info) when **`ImageResolution -> 72`**:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/211uP.png"];
Image[img, ImageResolution -> 72]
```

[image]

Alternatively, using a `Graphics` to wrap the `Image[…]` will also transform the coordinates to the standard image coordinate system:

```
Graphics[img, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

With either of the methods above, the correct coordinates can be obtained:

[image]

Comment: Wow, so much useful information. I'll digest it thoroughly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/211uP.png"]
```

First get the `ImageDimensions`:

```
ImageDimensions[img]
```

> {498, 406}

```
ImageTrim[img, {{120, 100}, {480, 360}}]
```

These coordinates are {x1,y1}, {x2,y2} (lower left, upper right).

---

or you could try:

```
ImageTake[img, {40, 300}, {120, 480}]
```

---

[image]