# Problem when extracting data of a closed curve from a black and white image: how to find the correct transformation of coordinates?

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to extract the data of the closed curve from a black and white image.

But the coordinates of the curve I extraced are wrong, as seen in my result [image: my results are wrong.].

**For example, the x-coordinate of my result ranges from -150 to 0, which is different from the true range, i.e., -6 to 6.**

I found some very useful discussions here about extracting data from images.

However, when I tried to apply the techniques discussed to extract data from a black and white image, the results were incorrect.

Here is my naive try. Where did I go wrong?

It seems I didn't find a correct transformation?

Any suggestions? Thank you.

```
imgImport = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0KCa.png"];
img = ImageTake[imgImport, {55, 286}, {125, 469}]

cor = ImageValuePositions[img, {0., 0., 0.}];
{o, x, y} = {{6.56169201921564`, 
    22.11360816415005`}, {28.934949660676992`, 
    5.2325141690732515`}, {6.679185088841892`, 6.554693779835269`}};
trans = FindGeometricTransform[{o, y}, {{-6, -14}, {-6, 16}}][[2]];

ListPlot[trans /@ cor]
```

[image: image-to-be-digitized]

Comment: Would you like to reproduce `img`  with `ListPlot`?

Comment: Could you explain what it is you're trying to achieve, and how the current results of your current code differ from that?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks! Yes, I want to reproduce `img` with `ListPlot` :)

Comment: @MelaGo Thanks for your attension. I am trying to extract data of the closed curve in the image, but the result I got are wrong. For example, the x-coordinate of my result ranges from `-150` to `0`, which is different from the true range, i.e., `-6` to `6`.

Comment: @xinxinguo We should know some points on this curve.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Maybe I am wrong, but I think the axes coordinates are sufficient to derive all the cooridnates on the curve, as done by PlotDigitizer (https://plotdigitizer.com/).  The idea is to first calibrate the axis/axes and then get the coordinate data.

Comment: @xinxinguo Unfortunately  `FindGeometricTransform` is not so advanced function. Even with given points we can't compute the right transformation. Without given points with visual information only the best way is what MelaGo shown below.

Comment: ……1. A unique transformation cannot be determined by two points, you need to use three points. 2. `ListPlot[Thread@Callout[{o, x, y}, {"o", "x", "y"}]]` 3. After `ImageTake`, the coordinate system of the image will of course change, `trans/@cor` is obviously wrong.

Comment: @xzczd Your advice is always very helpful, and I finally understand where I went wrong. Thank you!

Comment: 4. The ordering of coordinates in `FindGeometricTransform` should be reversed i.e. `{(* new coordinates *), (*old coordinates*)}`. 5. Please refer to my answer to your previous question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/299961/1871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approximation.

Identify axes

```
ls = ImageLines[ColorNegate@imgImport, .2];
HighlightImage[imgImport, ls]
```

[image]

Find the origin

```
origin = Flatten[MeshPrimitives[RegionIntersection[MeshRegion /@ ls], 0] /. 
   Point -> List]
  (* {111.145, 85.2972} *)
```

Crop the image at the axes

```
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[imgImport];
img = ImageTake[imgImport, {0, h - origin[[2]]}, {origin[[1]], w}]
```

[image]

Get the coordinates from the cropped image and transform according to a manual inspection of the axes

```
d = ImageValuePositions[img, {0., 0., 0.}];
{w2, h2} = ImageDimensions[img];
dtxf = {(#[[1]]/w2) 12 - 6, (#[[2]]/h2) 34 - 16} & /@ d;

ListPlot[dtxf, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]